# shoutcast player in java

Tags: java, stream, shoutcast

i want to create a java program which can play shoutcast radios. I started with [javazoom](http://www.javazoom.net/projects.html) but it displays an error about invalid http. Also i download jlGui(from the same site) and it has the same problen as my program which i create. Finally i try a lot of radio stations but i have the same problem. if anyone knows another way or some java libs i will appreciate it! thanx

```
import javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicController;
import javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayer;
import javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayerEvent;
import javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayerException;
import javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayerListener;

try {
            player = new BasicPlayer();
            playerControl = (BasicController) player;
            player.addBasicPlayerListener(this);
            try {
                playerControl.open(new URL(streamurl));
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                System.out.println("aaa");
            }
            playerControl.play();
            playerControl.setGain(0.85);
            playerControl.setPan(0.0);
        } catch (BasicPlayerException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
```

error message

```
javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayerException: 
java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must set javaSE 1.6 not 1.7!